# Impact of adding namespace on existing code

Tags: soql, package, namespace

I am trying out few Lightning stuff and as a part of that I added namespace to my Developer edition.
After doing this I realized that all my preexisting custom object's API name is now prefixed with the namespace.
e.g. 
object name before adding namespae - MyCustomObject__c
object name after adding namespace - MyNamespace__MyCustomObject__c

My existing Apex code which is using MyCustomObject__c is working fine. But any new query that I am firing from dev console requires me to add namespace prefix.

my questions is -

what is the impact of adding namespace ?
1. Do we need to revisit all apex code/soql query ?
2. Do we need to recreate enterprise WSDL  and correct SOAP API calls ?

Any insight on this would be very helpful.

Comment: FYI - as of Spring '15 Lightning no longer requires a namespace.

Comment: Correct Mike. but I realized that after adding the namespace and now I can't undo it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically you don't have to revisit all of your code. Most things will continue to run after the prefix is added.

But **most** doesn't mean **all**. I found these points requiring modifications:

- Objects accessed via API
- as a consequence existing integrations and ETL processes
- Metadata accessed via API including use of Metadata Service.cls for APEX
- Usage of Ajax Toolkit
- JavaScript Remoting for Apex Controllers (at least where I used alternate syntax)
- places where I heavily used Schema methods together with SObject.get() and dynamic SOQL e.g. for this baby here:  [Howto wildcard SELECT * to query all fields of objects in APEX?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/49711/howto-wildcard-select-to-query-all-fields-of-objects-in-apex)
- this list is likely incomplete. Additions are welcome!

What I try to do is wherever possible to write code that runs with and without namespace and I pay a lot of attention never to hardcode any namespace reference.

With a bit effort you'll get all references dynamically prefixed. Mind that in JS you have to do it at some places with 'prefix.' and in Apex or API typically with 'prefix__'

If you hardcode that you loose portability, meaning you can't just copy or deploy all of your code to a different Org. And this can be serious.

For lightning I asked [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/58038/use-dynamic-namespace-references-in-lightning-components) which was answer by Doug and Peter and should cover most aspects.